# How to copy data from <p> tag [copy to clipboard]

Tags: html

my query is about copy data available in div tag or pre tag or a a tag basically any tag apart from input. so data available in these tags should be copy to  clipboard as many times i clicked on button

Comment: please share, what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've tried method available here
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/copy-to-clipboard-made-easy-with-clipboardjs--cms-25086

Comment: I'm.not sure I understand what you are wanting to do. Do you mean you have one button and, whenever you click it, you want the text content of *all* non-`input` elements on the page to be put on the clipboard?

Comment: yes like,
you are working on a table and in one column having some  names of user that can be in anchor tag or div tag with a button so whenever i click on button(if names are in div tag ) or directly click on name(if in anchor tag so that should be copy to clipboard)

Comment: <td>
    <div>Smith</div>
   <button>copy</button>
</td>

Comment: Add the code to your question @div47 ... This is a low quality question and you are less likely to get an answer if you are not being detailed with the issue you are currently having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using javascript.

```
<p id="text_element">Copy this !</p>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('text_element')">
Copy to clipboard
</button>
```

Now use the following script

```
function copyToClipboard(elementId) {
var aux = document.createElement("input");
aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);
document.body.appendChild(aux);
aux.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
document.body.removeChild(aux);}
function log() {
console.log('---')
}
```

This function is creating a hidden input. then it is Executing the copy command. In the end, it is Removing the input from the body

Comment: This is correct but it is working for only first element.
like i am working on a table so i've implemented this in my table. for in a column(consider as user name column) so whenever i click on button it'll copy only first name